# how to put angularjs template tag {{myitem}} in video player javascript

Tags: angularjs, video-player

Below is a snippet of code I want to maked  work,also it will be  interested how to put angular data in a php string like the one below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Api">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-ng-controller="detaliivideo">

           {{afisare.video}} <!--  this is showing the data in pure html -->

         <!--  but in javascript no -->

           <script type="text/javascript">

           // in a simple variable also not working
           var video = {{afisare.video}};
               var flashvars = {
                    'autoplay':1,
                    'autohide':0,
                    'skin':'//www.mysite.net/js/clipuri.swf',
                    'more':'//www.mysite.net/related.php',
                    'ecode':'',         
                    'video': {{afisare.video}}, // this is not working, '{{afisare.video}}' not working also ,"{{afisare.video}}" not working also
                    'thumbnail':''
                                 };
           </script>
<?php $var = "{{myItem}}"; // echo $var is showing the data ,but in a function name ($var) is showing {{afisare.video}}?>
    </div>
```